# cover standardsetcontroller in test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, standardsetcontroller

```
public SFA_LeadNewOverride_VFC(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {                                                                 
    recId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'); 
    if(String.isNotBlank(recId) && 
        recId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName() == 'Account') {
        accId = recId; accOnLead = [Select Id,Name FROM Account WHERE Id   =:recId LIMIT 1];                                                                     
    }
```

I am trying this

```
ApexPages.StandardSetController setstd = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(leadRecord);
SFA_LeadNewOverride_VFC objVFCset = new SFA_LeadNewOverride_VFC(setstd);
```

But it gives error

> Compile Error: Constructor not defined:
>   [ApexPages.StandardSetController].(Lead)

Comment: `StandardSetController` takes a list/set of records in constructor, not a single record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [StandardSetController constructor](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_ApexPages_StandardSetController_constructors.htm) requires a list (or Database.QueryLocator) parameter e.g.:

```
... = ApexPages.StandardSetController(new Lead[] {leadRecord});
```